# Google Cloud SQL front-end options, or RAD suggestions?

Tags: sql, web-applications, crm

I'm interested in changing our contact-relationship-management system to Google's Cloud SQL, but I can't seem to find a good modular, customizable, front-end application that can utilize it.

I know a little bit of Java and SQL, but having only made a few small applications and a few queries, starting a project of this magnitude from scratch is daunting.

I'd prefer a RAD tool that can develop a front-end for the users. Our current CRM application, Sage ACT! 2009, has a layout editor that feels just like Visual Basic's designer. It also handles all the back-end SQL stuff. This is basically what I want, but needs the ability to connect to a remote database.

Google Apps integration would rock, but I know nothing about web applications or GAE. We have Google Apps for Business.

In short, I want either customizable front-end database client software (focused on users, not on database administration), or a RAD tool that is somewhat CRM-oriented and works with SQL out of the box.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45325/app-for-rapid-prototyping-of-relational-data-structures

Comment: **Not found:** https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45325/app-for-rapid-prototyping-of-relational-data-structures

Answer (score 0):

I endorse this, and have a suggestion.

`Microsoft Access` is arguably one of the best, and certainly most frequently used, end-user RAD tools available. Its forms and subforms make it possible to present and update data in a very intuitive way.

How difficult would it be to create an ODBC driver for `Google Cloud SQL`? Does one already exist? An ODBC driver would permit Google Cloud tables to be visible within Access as attached tables.

Comment: MarkRennes: Please do research this. An answer is not the place to pose more questions.